# ansible set file descriptor values such as nproc and nofile linux

Tags: linux, ansible-2.x

I have Below Playbook to set the file descriptor values for a user in linux, I have below code which is tested and working fine i am looking if shorten the code using something like `vars`.

Precisely, i want to use the module `pam_limits` one and cover the both the actions of increasing `nofiles` & `nproc` values at once.

```
---
- name: Setting File-descriptor Values for db_user
  hosts: all
   become: yes
   become_method: sudo
   become_user: root
   tasks:
    - name: Setting-up file-max limit
      sysctl:
       name: fs.file-max
       value: '1618107'
       state: present
       reload: yes

    - name: setting-up nofile limit
      pam_limits:
       domain: db_user
       limit_type: "{{ item }}"
       limit_item: nofile
       value: '260000'
      loop:
       - soft
       - hard

    - name: setting-up nproc limit
      pam_limits:
       domain: db_user
       limit_type: "{{ item }}"
       limit_item: nproc
       value: '16383'
      loop:
       - soft
       - hard
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, you can use as follows with the `loop` However, I see your `soft` and `hard` limit values are an Identical hence you can better use `-` as i mentioned below in the comments itself.

```
---
- name: Setting File-descriptor Values for db_user
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: Setting-up file-max limit
      sysctl:
        name: fs.file-max
        value: 1618107
        state: present
        reload: yes
    - name: Setting-up nofles and nproc limit for db_user
      pam_limits:
        domain: db_user
        limit_type: "{{item.limit_type}}"
        limit_item: "{{item.limit_item}}"
        value: "{{item.value}}"
      loop:
        # Add nofile and nproc, both soft and hard, limit for the user db_user with a comment.
        # Type "-" for enforcing both soft and hard resource limits together for more details read `man limits.conf`.
        - { limit_type: '-', limit_item: 'nofile', value: 260000 }
        - { limit_type: '-', limit_item: 'nproc', value: 16383 }
```

Comment: Karn Kumar,  thank you for the solution +1 already, in case we have define `soft` and `hard` limits separately then there is a way to do it diffidently.